# how to export python files in Eclipse using pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, export

I currently have a project in eclipse and Im using Pydev, and im trying to export all the source code..I know how to to export java files into a jar file but my question is how can you export python files in eclipse ? or can you even do that ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python isn't like Java - it's an interpreted from the source files. Your `*.py` files are the only artefacts you need.

You may have seen `*.pyc` and `*.pyo` files around, but these are not *needed*, and don't inherently run faster than plain `.py` files. Read more [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html).

If you're looking to distribute your python code publicly, you may want to take a look at the [python packaging documentation.](http://guide.python-distribute.org/)

Comment: To add on a bit: Both Java and Python are interpretted languages, but Java has the nice option if creating a runnable jar. If you are interested in making an executable out of your python project I suggest you look up Py2exe

Comment: Sorry, yes I was misleading - I meant that Python isn't interpreted from some compiled form as Java is :) Thanks.

Comment: @KarlBarker it seems link is no more valid, please update.